# How to use the Kotlinx.html in Spring in place of the normal html template engine for JSP or Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, java-8, kotlinx-html

The flaw of the traditional html template engine is the absence of type-safe and compile-time checking. Some gurus suggested that [*Kotlinx.html*](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html) might greatly compensate the flaw of traditional html template engine.

So I plan to make use of Spring in *Java* without the html template engine, say without `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` nor `SpringTemplateEngine`, instead inject the *kotlin* code with *kotlinx.html*. But currently I've go clue at all how to proceed

Answer (score 2):

Right now I'm just returning a string with the kotlin html dsl as the return statement and the `@ResponseBody` annotation on the controller method.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class MyController constructor(){

  @GetMapping
  @ResponseBody
  fun index(): String {

    return myKotlinHtmlView()
  }
}
```

where `myKotlinHtmlView()` is the function where the template is